# Shortcut to change value of the developer option

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

My case: during day to day phone (Samsung Galaxy S7) usage I have monochromatic color space turned on from developer options in 'Simulate color space'. But sometimes I would like to turn back to normal color space. Is there possibility to create shortcut to change that option directly from main screen or at least open Developer Options on certain position?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut

Answer (score 0):

You can open a settings page from your home screen by adding a **shortcut**.

Open the Widgets/Shortcuts on your launcher (I can do so by long-pressing an empty space on my home screen) and scroll down to Settings. Then tap the Settings shortcut and select the settings page you want that shortcut to open to. You will want to select Developer Options.

---

Also, some accessibility options are available in your Quick Settings (settings above your notifications). You may be able to edit your Quick Settings tiles to include color space (I have a Quick Setting tile named **Greyscale** which comes from Google's [**Digital Wellbeing app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.wellbeing).